# where are the "best of the 90s", "billboard top 10 of 1982"-style suggestion lists in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I'm in the iTunes Store for the first time in forever, looking to buy some music.  (iTunes 11.0.2)

There used to be helpful lists like "best of the 90s", "billboard top 40" by year, and so on.

Where are all those helpful lists of songs?  They appear to be gone.  Please let me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes Essentials. Full list here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/essentials

Most popular lists are shown on the main page, and you can browse them all alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks -- I wonder why they removed it from the iTunes Store?  Weird to me.